# Adjoint of sum = sum of adjoints

Tags: functional-analysis

is $\mathcal{D}(A)=\mathcal{D}(B)$ a sufficient condition for $(A+B)^*=A^*+B^*$ , where $A$ and $B$ are densely defined (not necessarily symmetric) operators on some Hilbert space?

Comment: Certainly not. Consider the case A=-B.

Comment: Is it really a counterexample?

Comment: Or do you mean that we have to assume at least that $A^*$ resp. $B^*$ have dense domain?

Comment: $(A+B)^*=0$, $A^*+B^*=0|_{D(A^*)}$.

Comment: Yes, so could we save the statement by assuming that $\mathcal{D}(A^*)$ and $\mathcal{D}(B^*)$ are dense?

Comment: @user51527: No, if $A=-B$ then $(A+B)^*$ is *everywhere* defined, so unless $A^*$ is everywhere defined (i.e. bounded, by the closed graph theorem), the equality will not hold as written.

Comment: Okay, but $A^*-A^*=0\upharpoonright_{\mathcal{D}(A^*)}$ is a bounded densely defined operator and therefore has a unique extension to $0$ on the whole space. What seems to go wrong, is that we lose closedness. One last try: what if $B$ is in addition $A$-bounded with $A$-bound strictly less than 1?

Comment: I guess I should have assumed that  $A,B$ are closed in the first place.

Comment: ADJOINT OF SUMS AND PRODUCTS OF OPERATORS INHILBERT SPACES https://arxiv.org/pdf/1507.08418.pdf   This paper give condition for this to hold.

Comment: I know this is an old question, but OP was almost right in its last comments. If $A$, $B$ are closed operators, and we assume $B$ to be $A$-bounded and $B^*$ to be $A^*$-bounded both with relative bounds strictly less than one, then $(A+B)^*=A^*+B^*$. This is Corollary 1 in P. Hess, T. Kato, Perturbation of Closed Operators and Their Adjoints, Comment. Math. Helv., 45 (1970) 524-529. In particular, this property reduces to Kato-Rellich's theorem when $A$ is self-adjoint and $B$ is symmetric.